# nginx redirect all https url to the only 443 server block

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I configured three server blocks on my nginx server: 2 listening on 80 (http) and one listening on 443 (https).

The https server block conf file is as below:

```
server {
server_name foo.example.com;

location / {
    root  /var/nginx_root/yt/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/........ # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/...... # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/.......
}

server {
    if ($host = foo.example.com {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen  80;
    server_name foo.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

In the http server blocks, the server_name is set too.

These server blocks works well, but if I enter any https url other than the one defined in https server block, it get redirected to the https://foo.example.com !

For example if I enter https:blabla.example.com it get redirected to https:foo.example.com

It seems that as there is only one https block, all https requests go to this one, regardless of server_name !

What I need is that if I enter https:blabla.example.com it return 404 as no block with this server_name exists.

Thanks

Comment: That `SSL` thing seems — not — to be a `server` block. Try.